# Using adjective of number

Tags: adjectives

Which of the following does "There are three dogs and cats" mean?

1. There are three dogs and three cats.
2. There are three dogs and there are also some cats.
3. There are 3 animals; they can be either a dog or a cat.

Comment: what do you mean by three dogs and cats?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it could mean any of them, but I think that most people would **guess** that it means the following:

***"There are three animals, which include at least one dog and at least one cat."***

Note that this is different to the option 3 you give, "There are 3 animals; they can be either a dog or a cat.".  This could logically refer to 3 dogs (since each of the dogs is "a dog or a cat"), but you would never call three dogs "three dogs and cats": you would only say this if it was a mix of dogs and cats.

Answer (score 0):

A complete sentence example would have been better to understand the meaning, but the given phrase should usually imply **There are 3 animals; they can be either a dog or a cat.**

Three is a **quantifier** in this case which applies to a set of nouns (dogs and cats). As a similar case, we could say

There are more than a hundred *birds, animals and reptiles* in the local zoo.

In this example, the indeterminate quantifier *more than a hundred* is applied to the collection of objects of type *birds, animals and reptiles* taken **together** - the zoo might just have 10 reptile species in it.

Well, one way the above would be wrong is if the complete sentence was *There are three dogs and cats are their favorite prey to chase* ;-)